Associate a teams Sharepoint website with a hub site
I am an end user who is looking to deploy an sharepoint website for my department. I know that my organisation in the next year will deploy a hub site.
I need the Sharepoint website to a) collaborate as a team, which leads me to think a teams Sharepoint website is best. However I also want to have a website viewable by other persons in our organisation so that they know what our department does. I can see this can be achieved by either making a public teams Sharepoint, or a communication Sharepoint website.
I am not concerned if users find our public teams Sharepoint website / link and join our team. Therefore, I am considering using a teams Sharepoint website to achieve both goals.
However I have not been able to identify if a teams Sharepoint website can be associated with the hub site. The documentation available does not specify. Can this be done?

Yes you can assign a hub to a team site. I just checked and tried in admin center:

Team sites are just site collections with a different template and different features activated.
I would create both. A team site for internal communication and collaboration and a communication site for representation within the company.

Thank you for checking specifically. I'm much obliged. And yes, I do see the advantage in creating two websites and I think I will end up doing just that.
